# Let ψ be a homomorphism from a finite group G to itself. Show that the index of ψ(G) in G equals the order of the kernel of ψ.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **QUESTION:** Let ψ be a homomorphism from a finite group G to itself. Show that the
>   index of ψ(G) in G equals the order of the kernel of ψ.

I know the following 2 theorems might be helpful:

$\textbf{First Isomorphism Theorem}$: Let G be a group and $\Phi$: $G\rightarrow$H be a surjective homomorphism of groups. Then, if N is the kernal of $\Phi$, we have G/N $\cong$ H.

**Lagrange's Theorem:** The magnitude of the index of a subgroup H in a group G = 
$|G:H|$ = $\frac{|G|}{|H|}$.

Comment: If $\psi$ is injective the result is trivial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N=\ker\psi$ and $H=\psi(G)$, then the first isomorphism theorem says $|G|=|H|\,|N|$, and Lagrange's theorem that $|G|=|H|\,|[G:H]|$. Now equate the right hand sides and simplify by $|H|$.

By the way this fails if $G,H$ are infinite, even if $N$ and $[G:H]$ are finite. You can see this by taking $\psi:\mathbf Z\to\mathbf Z$ to be the homomorphism of multiplication by $n$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Denote by $N$ the kernel of $\psi$. Note that $G/N$, as the set of cosets (or equivalence classes) is uniform in the sense that all its elements have the same size as $N$.

(Then use the fact that we can divide finite cardinals under certain circumstances.)

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the index of a subgroup $H$ is the number of cosets, which in the finite case is equal to $[G:H] = |G|/|H|$. Now the First Isomorphism Theorem tells you that $|\psi(G)||\ker(\psi)| = |G|$. What does this say about the index of $\psi(G)$?